# Add 1 or many list[string][string] to a new list in LUA

Tags: lua

I have a number of large lists that are formatted like this...

```
listA = {}
   listA['Suburb Name A']['Street Name'] = {data1 = 'Stuff', data2 = 'stuff, data3 = 'stuff}
   listA['Suburb Name B']['Street Name'] = {data1 = 'Stuff', data2 = 'stuff, data3 = 'stuff}
   listA['Suburb Name C']['Street Name'] = {data1 = 'Stuff', data2 = 'stuff, data3 = 'stuff}
   listA['Suburb Name D']['Street Name'] = {data1 = 'Stuff', data2 = 'stuff, data3 = 'stuff}
   excreta... .. . 


listB = {}
   listB['Suburb Name E']['Street Name'] = {data1 = 'Stuff', data2 = 'stuff, data3 = 'stuff}
   listB['Suburb Name F']['Street Name'] = {data1 = 'Stuff', data2 = 'stuff, data3 = 'stuff}
   listB['Suburb Name G']['Street Name'] = {data1 = 'Stuff', data2 = 'stuff, data3 = 'stuff}
   listB['Suburb Name H']['Street Name'] = {data1 = 'Stuff', data2 = 'stuff, data3 = 'stuff}
   excreta... .. .
```

What I am trying to do is copy these lists into a new list, a new list that is both the list combined.

Something like this..

```
ListNew = {}
ListNew = Add(listA, ListNew )
ListNew = Add(listB, ListNew )
ListNew = Add(listC, ListNew )
```

Any ideas?

(Edited to remove my erroring code and try to make the question more clear, by only putting in basic information needed.)

Comment: You don't need to explain an edit; there's a special text box for that when editing an answer or question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Thanks to anyone that tried to help.

```
function add(target, source)
    for i in pairs(source) do
        if target[i] == nil then
            target[i] = {}
        end
        for j in pairs(source[i]) do
            target[i][j] = source[i][j]
        end
    end
end

-- used like this
newList = {}
add(newList, listA)
add(newList, listB)
add(newList, listC)
```

Comment: I think that writing the question and answer took more time than writing the `add` function.